# Migrating Oracle to MySQL: MySql Workbench Not Available

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration

I am currently trying to migrate information from a query of a remote Oracle database to a local MySQL database. I have poked around and have found it has been frequently suggested to use the Migration tool in MySQL Workbench. However, I am developing through ssh and only have control of the linux cloud environment I'm working in through the terminal.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can export the result to csv file, you could use [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ssh to securely forward the MySQL port remotely. For example, if you execute:

```
ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 <ssh-user>@<remote-server>
```

You will be able to connect to the local port 3307 as if MySQL was running there. All connection information will be tunneled though ssh, so it will be sent securely. That way you can connect using Workbench using `localhost:3307`

I cannot say if Workbench would be the best tool for the migration, though. Here you have some pointers and tools: http://database-scalability.blogspot.com.es/2014/04/porting-from-oracle-to-mysql.html